# UAA or non oidc oauth2 in jhipster-control-center

Tags: jhipster

Is there a way to configure [jhipster-control-center](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-control-center) for use with jhipster UAA authentication or non-oidc oauth2 authentication?

I tried setting env parameters on the container for standard oauth2 but I'm unable to login.

```
export SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_URI="https://{domain}/oauth/token"
export SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_USER_AUTHORIZATION_URI="https://{domain}/oauth/authorize"
export SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCE_USER_INFO_URI="https://{domain}/api/account"
export SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_CLIENT_ID="{clientId}"
export SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_CLIENT_SECRET="{clientSecret}"
```

Comment: Something about UAA: it has been removed from version 7 of JHipster, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/13081

Comment: Standard oauth2 without oidc should continue to be supported though correct?